# What's going wrong with my UIBezierPaths?

Tags: ios, json, uibezierpath

[image: Raw and restore bezier paths drawn to screen]

On top are the bezier paths I'm attempting to encode/decode to/from JSON. On bottom are the paths after they get decoded.

Comparing the actual data, all the points and control points are the same. For instance, the top curve of the B is:

```
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 106, y: 35))
path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 135, y: 47), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 106, y: 35), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 135, y: 31))
path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 105.5, y: 59.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 135, y: 63), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 105.5, y: 59.5))
```

in JSON it is:

```
 "elements" : [
      {
        "type" : "MoveTo",
        "x" : 106,
        "y" : 35
      },
      {
        "x" : 135,
        "y1" : 35,
        "y" : 47,
        "x1" : 106,
        "y2" : 31,
        "x2" : 135,
        "type" : "CubicCurveTo"
      },
      {
        "x" : 105.5,
        "y1" : 63,
        "y" : 59.5,
        "x1" : 135,
        "y2" : 59.5,
        "x2" : 105.5,
        "type" : "CubicCurveTo"
      }
    ],
```

And yet they draw differently.

Can anyone spot what's missing from the bottom paths?

Comment: This is using https://github.com/illyabusigin/UIBezierPathSerialization btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that when the paths were being read in from the JSON, all curves were marked as `kCGPathElementAddQuadCurveToPoint` rather than `kCGPathElementAddCurveToPoint`.

(Submitted a pull request to the library)

Comment: wasted like 4 hours on this, using the library via CocoaPods gets you an outdated version, even though the change was committed

Comment: @Andrespch yeah, I wish there was a better way to ping repo owners... :/